How would I access an already running flask app, running on a localhost server (<my_ip>:5000), from a different file like an API?
I have two files, one titled 'main.py' which contains this code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/users")
def home():
    return ('Name, Date of Birth, Occupation <br/> <br/>'
            ' John Doe, 3/14/1977, Director John Doe Healthcare <br/>'
            'Joe Doe, 2/17/1972, Entrepreneur <br/>'
            'Joseph Doe, 5/11/07, Student <br/>'
            'Jotaro Doe, 8/30/09, Student')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

And a second file called 'main_getter.py.' What I want to do from 'main_getter.py.' is access the
(<my_ip>:5000) server and, like an API, access Data from the simple flask page. I can't figure out how to get access to the same flask app from a different file. How would I do it?
I want the end result to be so that when I enter someone's name as a parameter in a GET function, I get everything about that person.

You can use requests to call your flask app from another python code, if that is what you want https://pypi.org/project/requests/

if you want to use it as API then better send it as JSON instead of HTML. It can be simpler to work with data.

or send it as CSV - but this needs normal \n instead of <br>. And better remove spaces after ,

You can use standard module urllib
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:5000/users')
print(response.read())

Or you can use external module requests
import requests

response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/users')
print(response.text)


You can also test server using commands in terminal.
On Linux popular commands are curl or wget.
curl http://localhost:5000/users


EDIT:
Example which works like API.
First function works as /users/Joe
Second function works as /other?name=Joe
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import io
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

data = (
    'Name,Date of Birth,Occupation\n'
    'John Doe,3/14/1977,Director\n'
    'John Doe,3/14/1977,Healthcare\n'
    'Joe Doe,2/17/1972,Entrepreneur\n'
    'Joseph Doe,5/11/07,Student\n'
    'Jotaro Doe,8/30/09,Student'
)


@app.route("/users/")
@app.route("/users/<name>")  # <-- name
def home(name=None):         # <-- name # `None` as default value for `route("/users/")`

    # create file-like object 
    f = io.StringIO(data)
    
    # convert to DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(f)  
    #print(df)
    
    if name:
        # search name in DataFrame
        df = df[ df['Name'].str.contains(name) ]   
    
    # convert DataFrame to JSON
    json = df.to_json(orient='records')
    
    return json


@app.route("/other/")
def other():

    name = request.args.get('name') 
    
    # create file-like object 
    f = io.StringIO(data)
    
    # convert to DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(f)  
    #print(df)
    
    if name:
        # search name in DataFrame
        df = df[ df['Name'].str.contains(name) ]   
    
    # convert DataFrame to JSON
    json = df.to_json(orient='records')
    
    return json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

And code for script which gets data from API:
def version1a(value=""):
    print("--- version1a ---")

    import urllib.request
    import json
    
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://localhost:5000/users/{value}')
    
    text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    #print('text:', text)
    
    data = json.loads(text)    
    
    return data

def version2a(value=""):
    print("--- version2a ---")

    import requests
    
    response = requests.get(f'http://localhost:5000/users/{value}')

    #text = response.text
    #print('text:', text)

    data = response.json()

    return data

def version1b(value):
    print("--- version1b ---")

    import urllib.request
    import json
    
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(f'http://localhost:5000/other/?name={value}')
    
    text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    #print('text:', text)
    
    data = json.loads(text)    
    
    return data

def version2b(value):
    print("--- version2b ---")
    
    import requests
    
    payload = {'name': value}
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/other/', params=payload)
    #response = requests.get(f'http://localhost:5000/other?name={value}')

    #text = response.text
    #print('text:', text)

    data = response.json()

    return data

def display(data):
    from pprint import pprint

    pprint(data)

    for row in data:
        print(f'{row["Name"]} was born {row["Date of Birth"]} and works as {row["Occupation"]}')

# --- main ---

data = version1a()       # gives all data
display(data)
data = version2a()       # gives all data
display(data)

data = version1a('Joe')   # gives one result
display(data)
data = version2a('Joe')   # gives one result
display(data)

data = version1a('John')  # gives few results
display(data)
data = version2a('John')  # gives few results
display(data)

# - in args -

data = version1b('Joe')
display(data)

data = version2b('Joe')
display(data)

